# Is it possible to install iOS apps without iTunes or the App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I programmed an app for a company and would like to install the app on their iPads without having to submit the app to the App Store since its a commercial app for just this company. Is this possible without connecting each iPad to my MacBook and putting a developer certificate on it.

Is there another way? What about using an URL-link or QR-Code (linking to this url)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Your question is about installing apps without iTunes and the Apple App Store. This is entirely possible and supported by Apple but you are still bound by your developer account's ability to only build signed binaries for 100 devices for *testing purposes only*.

You can distribute your apps over the air via services like [hockeyapp.net](http://hockeyapp.net) and [testflightapp.com](http://testflightapp.com) (free) but these services are just hooking into the iOS system's ability to install signed binaries over the air which has been possible since iOS4. There are several open source projects that provide the bare bones HTML and Javascript/meta tags to install signed binaries over the net - one such one is [iOS Beta Builder](https://github.com/HunterHillegas/iOS-BetaBuilder)

If you are creating Enterprise apps for clients (that will exist in production, not just a development environment) then your only legitimate way to provide your clients with apps that won't expire is to use [Enterprise Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). The enterprise account has no device limits but the apps you sign with enterprise certs phone home to Apple each time they're launched and are strictly only allowed to be used for a single company and their current employees.

Comment: I tried to use testflightapp.com and it requires a provision profile. user1066006 doesn't have this subscription as I understand.

Comment: @Gargo Any of the services above can be used with a standard developer account but you need to use AdHoc distribution profiles (or Enterprise distribution profiles if you have them).

Answer (score -1):

It is because of Apple takes 30% of all the payments, isn't it?

The only way I see is to create usual web-site which runs via browser without installing

Comment: It is not about the 30%. OP can (and should) get an Enterprise Developer Account to do what he wants.

Comment: cydia is not a solution of your problem, is it?

Comment: As a developer, if you were building apps for a client, charging for it in the App Store is irrelevant.

Comment: i can't understand what do you mean. If you meaned developing for app store has the highest priority then read the question closely

Comment: @gargo the OP wants to distribute enterprise apps to his client without going through the App Store and without manually adding them via iTunes. What did I miss?